# tensorflow from_generator() giving error- 'generator` yielded an element that could not be converted to the expected type

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have written a generator for multi-input nn but while using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() function im getting error, all the data is in numpy where : input 1 is of shape(16,100,223,3), input 2 is of shape(100,223), input 3 is of shape (16,) and label is of shape(2,). data is a array of all these combined

my code

```
def data_generator(train_list, batch_size):

i = 0
j = 0
flag = True
while True:
    # inputs = []
    # outputs = []
    if i < len(train_list):
        if flag == True:
            train_path = os.path.join(training_dir, train_list[i])
            data = np.load(train_path, allow_pickle=True)
            flag = False

        if j >= len(data):
            j = 0
            i += 1
            flag = True
            del data

        else:
            if len(data[j:]) >= batch_size:
                input_1 = data[j:(j+batch_size), 0] 
                input_2 = data[j:(j+batch_size), 1]
                input_3 = data[j:(j + batch_size), 2]
                outputs= data[j:(j+batch_size), -1]
                j += (batch_size)
                yield {'Input_Branch-1' : input_1,'Input_Branch-2': input_2, 'Input_Branch-3': input_3}, outputs

            elif len(data[j:])< batch_size:
                input_1 = data[j:, 0]
                input_2 = data[j:, 1]
                input_3 = data[j:, 2]
                outputs= data[j:, -1]
                j = 0
                i+= 1
                flag = True
                del data
                yield {'Input_Branch-1': input_1, 'Input_Branch-2': input_2, 'Input_Branch-3': input_3}, outputs

    else:
        i = 0
        del data
        flag = True
        np.random.shuffle(train_list)


batch_size = 5
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, args= [train_list, batch_size],
                                         output_types = ({'Input_Branch-1': tf.uint8, 'Input_Branch-2': tf.uint8, 'Input_Branch-3': tf.float32}, tf.float32),)

# for seeing the output of data generator
num = 0
for data, labels in dataset:
    print(data.shape, labels.shape)
    print(labels)
    print()
    num = num + 1
    if num > 1: break
```

I'm getting the following error

```
 2020-08-04 17:43:30.653430: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1741] Invalid argument: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that could not be converted to the expected type. The expected type was uint8, but the yielded element was [array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
 array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
 array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
 array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
 array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)].
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\panwa\.conda\envs\Vision\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 801, in generator_py_func
    ret, dtype=dtype.as_numpy_dtype))

  File "C:\Users\panwa\.conda\envs\Vision\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 203, in _convert
    result = np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype, order="C")

  File "C:\Users\panwa\.conda\envs\Vision\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This same error is repeated multiple times
Please Help!!!

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No ,I was not able to solve it looking at other ways to feed the data, though would still appreciate help.

Comment: At the time I asked I was having the same error. My case was solved by correctly setting the **output_shapes** argument of from_generator(). Its a list or tuple of the shapes of the outputs. As I can see, you haven't set it either, so you could try this. Also, I don't know if that is applicable here, but why not breaking it to more generators?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, which I believe I solved by specifying the shape that the generator generated.
For me, the output was 2 images 32x32x3,as well as two labels so i used this, as an argument to the from_generator method.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator
    generator,
# this is the part that you care about #
    output_signature=(
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,32,32,3), dtype=tf.int32),
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,1), dtype=tf.int32,))
#
    )
```

I tried to run your code but train_list is not defined.
Still I believe that this could work, maybe with a change or two

```
output_signature = (
# the one is there to clarify that there is one of these objects
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,16,100,223,3),  dtype=tf.int32)
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,100,223), dtype=tf.int32)
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,16,) ,dtype=tf.int32)
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=(2,1),dtype=tf.int32)
)
```

Here is a link with a toy dataset that I made in order to make sense out of this mess

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17pu6jJYLGP-I1nJnzigOx2YOh3Ih4cvG?usp=sharing